# How to validate price range value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on my Add Materials for my Sales and Inventory. So far I need a validation where when adding a material, Selling Price must be greater than Purchase Price.

Here is my code and I'm getting an error in the if/else statement where the values of my txtPurchasePrice and txtSellingPrice are decimal(18, 2).

---

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSellingPrice.Text >= txtPurchasePrice.Text)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Materials VALUES (@UnitID, @Name, @SellingPrice, @PurchasePrice, " +
            "@Description, @Available, @CriticalLevel, @Maximum, @Status, @DateAdded, @DateModified)";                
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitID", txtUnitID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellingPrice", txtSellingPrice.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchasePrice", txtPurchasePrice.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDesc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Available", "0");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriticalLevel", txtCritical.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maximum", txtMax.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Available");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Helper.AddLog("1", "Add", "Added a new Material");
        Response.Redirect("~/Materials/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

---

My Error

> CS0019: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string'
>   and 'string'

Why is that `>=` or `<=` or `||` or `<` or `>` is cannot be used? in this case?

Comment: Because these operators are for numeric or enum values (except `||`). And how do you think one string can be "bigger or equal" to another string? This "bigger" subject will be complicated in text comparisons IMO..

Comment: Just wanted to be clear with the operators :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `txtSellingPrice` and `txtPurchasePrice` are `TextBox` controls, hence their `Text` property is of type `string`. You can't use `>=` since that has no semantical meaning. You'll need to parse the text first into `decimal`:

```
var sellingPrice = decimal.Parse(txtSellingPrice.Text);
var purchasePrice = decimal.Parse(txtPurchasePrice.Text);

if (sellingPrice >= purchasePrice)
{
   // stuff
}
```

If you're not sure the text is a valid `decimal` value, use `decimal.TryParse`:

```
decimal sellingPrice;
if (!decimal.TryParse(txtSellingPrice.Text, out sellingPrice))
{
   // Not a valid decimal, do something.
}

decimal purchasePrice;
if (!decimal.TryParse(txtPurchasePrice.Text, out purchasePrice))
{
   // Not a valid decimal, do something.
}

if (sellingPrice >= purchasePrice)
{
   // stuff
}
```

Comment: @Jules What integer? :)

Comment: thanks so much :) you actually answered my questions and it worked also!

Answer (score 2):

Hwo can a string be greater than another string?

You need to convert the string to a numeric value before you do the comparison.

Since you are dealing with money, you should use `Decimal`:

```
if (Decimal.Parse(txtSellingPrice.Text) >= Decimal.Parse(txtPurchasePrice.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the numeric value of two strings you have to parse them into a numeric type, e.g. double!

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToDecimal(txtSellingPrice.Text) >= Convert.ToDecimal(txtPurchasePrice.Text)

String value cannot be compared like that